# Gstreamer pipeline Sinking to rtspclientsink advise

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am trying to Sink a public HTTP stream (MJPEG) to "rtsp-simple-server" using Gstreamer rtspclientsink.

The following command works using fakesink. But um unable to get the rtspclientsink  to work. Note this public stream is an example.

FakeSink

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location="http://192.82.150.11:8083/mjpg/1/video.mjpg" ! jpegparse ! matroskamux ! fakesink
```

rtspclientsink Not Working

```
   gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location="http://192.82.150.11:8083/mjpg/1/video.mjpg" ! jpegparse ! matroskamux ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:8554/cam
```

I get the following error: WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link matroskamux0 to rtspclientsink0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have also tried

```
gst-launch-1.0  souphttpsrc location="http://192.82.150.11:8083/mjpg/1/video.mjpg" ! jpegparse ! rtpjpegpay ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://192.168.1.161:8554/cam
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `protocols=tcp sync=false` solved my problem.

Comment: can you post the gst-launch-1.0 command you got to work?

Comment: I would be interested also.  It's not clear why specifying tcp and no-sync would help.

Comment: @duane 
`videosrc="video.mp4"`

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspclientsink protocols=tcp name=s location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/stream filesrc location="${videosrc}" ! qtdemux name=d d.video_0 ! queue ! s.sink_0 d.audio_0 ! queue ! s.sink_1
`